# ADB shell and exec-out commands on same line

Tags: java, command, adb

I am trying to combine shell input keyevent KEYCODE_WAKEUP and exec-out screencap -p > C:\Test_code\adt_sma_automation\GUI\CurrentScreen.png on the same line.  any suggestions?  I tried quotes around entire command, &&, nothing works

Comment: What do you mean with `combine`?

Comment: trying to send them both on one line

Comment: What about using a pipe (`|`)?

Comment: as an example I can combine the following and it runs.  shell "input keyevent KEYCODE_WAKEUP && input touchscreen tap 739 27

Comment: using adb from windows cmd line

Comment: I think I figured it out! adb -s 12b1e4de shell "input keyevent KEYCODE_WAKEUP" && adb exec-out screencap -p > C:\Test_code\adt_sma_automation\GUI\CurrentScreen.png".  I needed to add an aditional adb before the exec-out command